# float left causes hover on right side of menu

Tags: css, css-float

I am curious if there's any way to correct this behavior using css only...

Notice that when you hover over the white space to the right of the menu it causes the blur of the menu items. If you hover over the white space to the left of the menu it does not blur the menu items.

I am sure that the float: left of the #centeredmenu ul rule is causing this blur. I would like to stop the blur when you hover over the white space to the right but this rule is necessary to center the menu.

I am trying to correct this page: http://www.soaringbirdstudios.com/help

As you can see in firebug I tried to add another div below the centermenu div with a style of clear both and enclosed both divs in an enclosing div but that didn't work. I just don't have enough experience to figure this one out.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't link to external pages and expect users to reverse-engineer them. Post an example as part of your question.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: I tried to fix your code, but you actually minified your CSS. Not gonna try to understand that. Don't minify CSS, seriously. The performance impact is minimal and it's just a pain in the butt. At least don't while you're in development. From what I could see though, the reason for this is that you used some weird methods for positioning your elements to the center. Relative positioning and floating... Un-float everything and remove all position stuff, and center elements normally, using text-align: center and/or margin: 0 auto;

Comment: I strongly disagree! Of course you should minify CSS, it's not a problem reading it with the proper browser's inspector tools (Chrome) - not to mention it takes about 1 min to send it through a unminify tool like: http://mrcoles.com/blog/css-unminify/ - every performance counts, saving 1kb is a lot after 10.000.000 visitors! Every bit helps for mobile devices as well.

Comment: @Diodeus sorry I wasn't aware.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help your exact desired solution, but if you mean wanting to get rid of the floats, you can simply do the following:

Change:

```
.bmenu li {
    display:inline-block;
    /*float: left;*/ <-- can delete or comment out
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    /*right: 50%;*/ <-- can delete or comment out
    margin: 100px 0 0;
    font-size: 50px;
    vertical-align:top; <--- added for making it pretty
}
```

Continue downwards with the following changes to get rid of floats completely:

`delete <div style="clear:both;"></div>`

```
#centeredmenu ul {
    /*clear: left;*/  <-- can delete or comment out
    /*float: left;*/  <-- can delete or comment out
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    /*left: 50%;*/  <-- can delete or comment out
    text-align: center;
}

#centeredmenu {
    /*float: left;*/ <-- can delete or comment out
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Any possibility you could upload the code after removing the floats? Would make it just a little easier to debug.

Comment: Did as you asked, now it blurs when hovering over both sides of the menu. Can't text indent either and logo is not showing correctly. Looks like you've created many more problems

Comment: Nah, you just misspelled a css rule that misplaced the elements. Ok good luck!

Comment: I'm looking at your solution again